# Integrated webcam on Dell XPS 15 L502X is not being detected in Lubuntu. What should I do?

Tags: lubuntu, webcam

The laptop which I'm using: Dell XPS 15 L502X
OS: Lubuntu

The problem is my webcam doesn't get detected  or doesn't work (I've tried it on cheese and a few other websites too). I have tried doing the fn+webcam key and downloaded other things but nothing has worked. By the way, it was working a few days ago but now it doesn’t.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Looks like the webcam might not be connected properly. Check the connection.